# Extracting full name from string using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, extract

"Name: Roger LeftPhone: (848) 274-9377Email: rogerleft@trueworld.ai"

What is the regex expression (javascript) that I need to extract "Roger Left" from the string above?

Thanks!!

Comment: What are the rules for extracting the string? Could the string be "Captain: Roger Left Email:..."? How about "Name: the Name: Roger Left Phone:...", or "name: Roger Left town in a hurry"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the name in group 1 with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/w06vaU/2):

```
Name:\s*(.*?)Phone:
```

We assume here, that the name is any string which starts immediately after "Name:" and ends at "Phone:".  The `\s*` pattern strips away the leading spaces from the name. The `:` after `Phone` is important, because it is possible that someone will have a name including `Phone`, for example:

```
Name: Phoney ChanPhone: .....
```

Without `:` after phone we would have matched the empty string in front of `Phoney`.

Answer (score 0):

```
^Name:\s(.+)Phone:\s(.+)Email:\s(.+)
```

This works as follows:

`^Name:` matches everything that starts with `Name:`
`\s` Matches all white spaces.
`(.+)Phone` matches all characters until `Phone`

With that you can get the name. The rest is for you to get the rest of the elements in case that is needed.

If you just need the name then `^Name:\s(.+)Phone:` should be enough.

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/w06vaU/2) for a playground